# Install a gas stove over vinyl flooring?

Tags: flooring, gas, stove, range

I just installed vinyl flooring over an old plywood subfloor. It used to be covered with very old linoleum. Now I'm installing a new gas range.

The stove manual says the floor needs to withstand 167-deg F (75 C). I'll call the company after the weekend and see what they say.

The range is an LG [LRG3061ST](http://www.lg.com/us/cooking-appliances/lg-LRG3061ST-gas-range), modern, middle-of-the-line:

[image: range]

The flooring is [Flexitec](https://www.ivcfloors.com/product/muse-538/) from IVC US.

I'm assuming my vinyl floor can't take the heat. If this is true, how should I proceed?

- Bare subfloor? This will create a higher ridge of vinyl where I cut it out.
- Sheet metal? It will eventually rust if I don't pay for stainless.
- Thin luan or plywood? Can I put it over the vinyl?
- Loose tile? I'd rather not glue and grout tile for this project.

Any other thoughts?

[image: flooring]

Comment: What is the make and model of this stove? I am amazed that any stove sold in the US requires a floor capable of withstanding 167 F (75 C). Maybe you could get a special insulating surface for wood stoves.

Comment: @JimStewart It's a modern range from LG, the LRG3016ST.  I've added info to the question.  I wonder if LG is just covering their backsides...

Comment: Is that a drawer on the bottom or is it the broiler? *Possibly* one could rest the feet on the vinyl and just have a metal sheet on little feet that slid into the space between the feet. A metal sheet with no air gap would conduct heat right to the vinyl. You would think something like that would be built into the bottom of the stove.

Comment: @JimStewart Drawer. Good thought though :)

Comment: Maybe modern vinyl flooring can withstand 75 C. I refuse to believe that LG would sell a standard range that could not be installed over all the standard kitchen  flooring materials.

Comment: @JimStewart Yeah, I would think so, too. I just send a "help request" to the flooring manufacturer. They don't have their phone number on their web page (grrr).  I'll come back and let you know what they say.